# Coverting Tiff to JPEG with Gdal_tranlate

Tags: gdal

I'm converting a 16-bit tiff image to JPEG with the gdal_translate library. But it drops from 16 bits to 8 bits. Is here any way that I can keep the bit depth at 16. Or should I need to get tiff image with higher bit depth.

**Options**

```
scale = "0-65535"
    options_list = [
        '-ot Byte',
        '-of JPEG', 
        '-b 1',
        '-co QUALITY=100',
        scale
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `-ot Byte` which is 8 bits by definition. I don't think UInt16 JPEG is supported. It should work with PNG.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the answer. I tried the solution it works as PNG, But like you said gdal_translate doesn't support that, I am getting a "One or more pixels clipped to fit 12bit domain for jpeg output." error while translating as JPG. So I think there is no way that I can go as JPG with 16 or more bit dept when I convert from tiff.